# Configure IIS 6 to deny access to specific file based upon IP address

Tags: iis-6

We are using IIS 6 as our webserver. And we need to deny the access for one specif file, placed in only one specific URL, to everybody OUTSIDE the local network.

In other words, if somebody is trying to access that filme/page from their own computer at home, using the internet, they must not succeed. But, if the same person try to do that at the same network of the web server, its ok.

I am not sure about that, but Apache uses ORDER DENY,ALLOW. You specify the URL, allow or deny to all or to a range of IP.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting an IP restriction on the file:

1. Open IIS MMC
2. Navigate to file in the website in question
3. Right click on the file and select 'Properties'
4. Select the 'File Security' tab
5. In the 'IP address and domain restrictions' pane, click Edit
6. Set the default restriction to deny access (click the Denied Access radio button)
7. Add an exception for your LCAN (click the Add button)
8. In the 'Grant Access' dialogue select 'Group of Computers' then enter the IP address and mask of your LAN: e.g. Network ID: 192.168.1.0, Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
9. Click OK on all the dialogues to return.